# Bézier Curve Didn't Draw Straight

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, bezier

I did make algorithm for creating Bézier Curve with Objective-C and Cocos2D. Here is my code

```
-(int)factorial:(int)x{
    int sum=1;
    int i;
    if(x == 0){
        return 1;
    }else{
        for(i=1;i<x;i++){
            sum = sum*i;
        }
        return sum;
        }
}

-(int)binomialCoefficient:(int)n:(int)i{
    int sum;
    //NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"fac n-i=%f\n", fach] );
    sum = [self factorial:n]/([self factorial:i]*[self factorial:(n-i)]);

    return sum;
}

-(float)convertT:(int)t{
    return t*(0.001);
}

-(float)power:(float)a:(int)b{
        int i;
    float hasil=1;
    for(i=0;i<b;i++){
        hasil = hasil*a;
    }
    return hasil;
}

-(float)bernstein:(float)t:(int)n:(int)i{
    float sum = 0;

    sum = [self binomialCoefficient:n:i]*[self power:t :i]*[self power:(1-t) :(n-i)];
    //NSLog([NSString   stringWithFormat:@"yeah"]);
    return sum;
}
```

and for implementation you just put an array of x and y and access it. For example to draw a single dot in control curve I did it like this

```
float myPx = px[i];
float myPy = py[i];
posx = posx+([self bernstein:theT :banyak-1 :i]*myPx);
posy = posy+([self bernstein:theT :banyak-1 :i]*myPy);
```

Yes, this code doesn't give the perfect nice line, but I try to draw it dot by dot.
It works well, but the problem arise when I try to use 3 dots. The middle dot for curving the lines didn't behave like what I expected. For example if I put 3 dots in these coordinates:
a(100,200)
b(250,250)
c(500,200)

It didn't curving up but curving down. If I want to put it straight I have to put it all the way higher.

Am I do it wrong in syntax or data types? Or is it just my algorithm?

Thanks in advance

Best Regards
(sorry for my bad english)

Comment: Replace your 'power' method with a call to the C library call pow(x, y). Also move your math-intensive stuff (ie factorial and binomial coefficients) into functions rather than method calls as this will be much more efficient. Also your syntax for calling the binomial method with two arguments looks wrong - does this code even compile?

Comment: @toiletseat: yep, arguments can be unnamed.

Comment: IIRC, the factorial loop should be `for(i=1;i<=x;i++)` instead of `for(i=1;i<x;i++)`, no? I mean, `4! = 4 × 3 × 2 × 1`

Comment: Ah yes, it's the factorial thing! Thanks @Cyrille !

Comment: Oh thanks @toiletseat , I tought Objective-C doesn't have the pow() :)
Yes, this code work, I just didn't put all the code here

Comment: @giripp Added my comment as answer so you can accept it and mark your question as solved. Also, remember that obj-C is a superset of C, so every C function (including `pow`) works straight. And your math functions should really be written as pure C functions, it's better for performance as you don't call the runtime for evaluating object methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The factorial loop should be

```
for ( i = 1 ; i <= x ; i++ )
```

instead of

```
for ( i = 1 ; i < x ; i++ )
```